# Does the minimum value of the S11 (return loss curve) at the resonance frequency depend on the resistance of the antenna?

Tags: antenna, resistance, nfc, vna, flexible

[image]

I was trying to fabricate a flexible NFC antenna. Initially, I fabricated my design on a copper PCB. It worked perfectly fine with my NFC chip and facilitated NFC communication. I observed its S11 curve using a NanoVNA with a loop probe, and it showed the minimum of the curve within the expected frequency range (around 13.6 MHz).

When I fabricated it on a flexible substrate (PET,) using silver nanoparticle ink, I found that the minimum of the S11 curve was lost. The antenna still worked fine with the NFC communication, but I got a flat curve everywhere, from 5 MHz to 50 MHz (I did not observe beyond that range.)

I measured the resistance of the flexible antenna and found that it has nearly 600 ohms of internal resistance, whereas my PCB antenna had about 2 ohms of resistance. Then, I connected my PCB antenna in series with a variable resistor and observed the S11 curve while varying the resistance of the variable resistor. I noticed that as the resistance increased, the minimum of the S11 curve gradually disappeared.
How could this happen, and what could be the reason behind this?

- Could the sensitivity of the NanoVNA be a reason for this?
- Can you explain how a vector network analyzer (VNA) works with loop probes when measuring the S11 curve of an NFC antenna?
- What is the working principle?

Since the antenna is not connected directly to the VNA, I am a bit curious to know about it. I used the instructions in the [AN2866 application note](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2866-how-to-design-a-1356-mhz-customized-antenna-for-st25-nfc--rfid-tags-stmicroelectronics.pdf) as my guide.

Comment: It might be worth telling us what the S11 minimum was for the rigid PCB solution and what the rest of the curve looks like (e.g. is it -10dB across the spectrum and -18dB at the 13.5MHz minimum).     When you are doing your sweep, is the NFC antenna connected to your NFC chip or is it shorted into a capacitor?

Comment: @RobinIddon here I added both S11 curves that I got for the PCB and flexible antennas. and yes, I connected the NFC antennas to the NFC chip when I did the sweep. I got a minimum of -12.2 dB at 12.9 MHz for the PCB antenna. but as you can see in the graph that I added to the question the flex antenna had a minimum of -0.46 dB at 20 MHz. and it did not go beyond -1 dB even at 50MHz.

Comment: I am not an RF guy.  Here's my simplistic understanding.  The S11 shows the power that is not returned to the VNA.  Normally it's 0dB ish meaning all the power is returned.   When you hit the resonance of your NFC antenna, power is transferred from the loop to the NFC antenna.  The more power that is transferred the lower (more negative) the S11.  Your NFC antenna can only absorb power by delivering to the input of the RF circuit.  It is typically a 50ohm to GND input. Your 600 ohm antenna can only transfer a fraction of the power because of its high impedance.

Comment: Assume the NFC antennas generate the same AC voltage as one another.  In the 600ohm case you have V^2/650 as the power absorbed.  In the 2ohm case you have V^2/52.  I haven't done the maths, but probably the ratio of 650 to 52 is close to -12dB 